# Set default font in XQuartz xterm?

Tags: x11, macos, xterm

With XQuartz 2.8.0_rc1 running on MacOS 10.15.7, when I run an xterm and ctrl-middle-click on an xterm I get a popup font menu as shown here. ***How can I set the default font so that all xterms open with, for example, UTF-8 encoding?***

Incidentally, I'm seeking this after the XQuartz update that I accepted yesterday. I previously used Terminal and xterm -- Terminal for vim editors (because the encoding was otherwise wrong) and xterm for everything else. But after yesterday's XQuartz update, I can no longer run xterm from within Terminal (well, they "run" but they don't display). So I want to use only xterm, but I need to be able to set the font encoding, preferably to UTF-8 since that seems to be what all my remote machines are using.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RTM. Going through the man page for xterm, the solution is to run xterm as follows:

```
xterm -en UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

XQuartz includes the [`uxterm`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/uxterm) script (`/opt/X11/bin/uxterm`), which looks for a workable locale using UTF-8 encoding, and sets the xterm resources to use the `UXTerm` class (which allows it to use suitable fonts).  The [uxterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/uxterm.html) manual page gives more information.

Setting the encoding without changing the fonts limits you to the ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) codeset, plus some workarounds for line-drawing.

XQuartz is actually a little old ([MacPorts](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/x11/xterm/Portfile) has an up-to-date copy of xterm, which includes support for TrueType font-sets).

Comment: I so regret allowing XQuartz to update itself the other day. I rely on working remotely and the MacBook is just a remote terminal to all my "real" computers. First, logged in via Terminal, remote X applications wouldn't display. So I decided I would run Xterm exclusively and no longer use Terminal. But now I find that some remote applications no longer run from my xterms. Will un-install XQuartz and try MacPorts' xterm...

Comment: Tried and failed to install xterm via MacPorts. I should have never updated.

Comment: You may not have installed `xorg-server` (`XQuartz` bundles all of the pieces, while MacPorts is *al la carte*).